# Globally disable https keycloak

Tags: ssl, https, keycloak

The deployment is on AWS and I do not want to tunnel to the box and open a browser to disable it.

There seems to exist a configuration: `"ssl-required":"none"` that can be placed in the `keycloak-server.json` file, but I'm not sure under which object.  I've tried under "realm" and by itself with no luck.

I do not want to disable it at the adapter level, it needs to be globally, so where does the `"ssl-required":"none"` go, or how can ssh/https be disabled globally?

(Also, I understand this is not recommended in production.)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In the "master" realm, over login tab. Change 'Require SSL' property to none.

If you can not access locally to keycloak and it is configured with a database for instance Postgres, then execute the following SQL sentence.

```
update REALM set ssl_required = 'NONE' where id = 'master';
```

It is necessary to restart keycloak

Comment: If you have only SSH access and Keycloak is running with embedded DB, you may use native DB client, e.g. for H2: java -cp <PATH TO H2>.jar org.h2.tools.Shell -url "jdbc:h2:file:<your DB>" -user <USER> -password <PASSWORD> -sql "update REALM set ssl_required='NONE' where id = 'master'"

Comment: E.g. `java -cp  modules/system/layers/base/com/h2database/h2/main/h2-1.4.193.jar org.h2.tools.Shell -url "jdbc:h2:./standalone/data/keycloak" -user sa -password sa -sql "update REALM set ssl_required='NONE' where id = 'master'"`

Answer (score 16):

I was run de Keycloak admin command to apply sslRequired=NONE.

```
$ docker exec -it CONTAINER-ID bash
$ cd /opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/
-- Run authenticate
$ ./kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user admin
-- Apply sslRequired to none
$ ./kcadm.sh update realms/master -s sslRequired=NONE
```

If you don't know user and/ou password I recomend run:

```
$ ./add-user-keycloak.sh --server http://localhost:8080/admin --realm master --user admin --password YOUR-PASSWORD
```

Comment: Inside docker container. I am getting this error:

    bash: cd: keycloak/bin: No such file or directory

Comment: the correct path for keycloak bin as the time writing this comment the latest version of ``kecloak is 12.0.4``

``/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin``

Comment: The authentication command failed when using `--server http://localhost:8080/auth`. It works when using `--server http://localhost:8080` instead. Ref: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/17.0/server_admin/index.html#authenticating

Answer (score 1):

Im my case, I'm using Keycloak Server with Spring Boot.
I can change sslRequired from Master Realm by code, extending the KeycloakApplication:

```
public class EmbeddedKeycloakApplication extends KeycloakApplication {
...

public EmbeddedKeycloakApplication() {
        super();        
        changeMasterRealm();
        ...
    }

private void changeMasterRealm() {
        KeycloakSession session = getSessionFactory().create();
        try {
            session.getTransactionManager().begin();
            RealmManager manager = new RealmManager(session);
            manager.getRealm("master").setSslRequired(SslRequired.NONE);
            session.getTransactionManager().commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {            
            session.getTransactionManager().rollback();
        }
       
...
```

Comment: Or you can use this to get the Realm:
`manager.getKeycloakAdminstrationRealm().setSslRequired(SslRequired.NONE);`

Answer (score 1):

I tried as below.

```
    docker run \
  --name new-keycloak \
  -dti \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin \
  -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin \
  -e KC_HOSTNAME=localhost \
  -e KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT=false \
  -e KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS=false \
  -e KC_HTTP_ENABLED=true \
  quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.2 \
  start-dev
```

but it still requires HTTPS. After searching more I saw a answer to do like below.

I started the container without any of the 4 "KC_" environment variables.
And then I went into the container and used kcadm.sh like this:

```
cd /opt/keycloak/bin
./kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080 --realm master --user admin
./kcadm.sh update realms/master -s sslRequired=NONE
```

Then it worked like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

The same image runs just fine on GKE, but when I try to run it on bare metal cluster (microk8s) it mandates tls... Could it be that ingress controller is different?