# Keycloak invalid redirect URI when deployed on openshift with https

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, openshift, redhat

I tried deploying jboss/keycloak with postgresql on openshift. When i enter the keycloak username/password, I am using secure route. It redirects me to the page that says, Invalid parameter: redirect_uri.

Environment variables on keycloak:

```
        - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
          value: admin
        - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
          value: admin
        - name: DB_VENDOR
          value: postgres
        - name: DB_PORT
          value: '5432'
        - name: DB_ADDR
          value: postgresql
        - name: DB_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: database-password
              name: postgresql
        - name: DB_DATABASE
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: database-name
              name: postgresql
        - name: DB_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: database-user
              name: postgresql`
```

When I remove the secure route, it works fine. How can i get it work in the `https` as well

Answer (score 1):

I have keycloak 7.0.0 docker behind ssl-terminating ingress proxy on kubernetes.

**If you are unable to login first time as administrator**:

First, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39129777/878241), switch keycloak to http mode.

```
update REALM set ssl_required = 'NONE' where id = 'master';
```

Second, put

```
 - name: KEYCLOAK_ALWAYS_HTTPS
   value: "true"
```

into your keycloak docker env.

After first step you will be getting "Invalid parameter: redirect_uri" error. Second step will fix that error and you will be able to login as administrator.

Your ingress should forward http port only.

All env variables for keycloak:

```
    - name: KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME
      value: "your.keycloak.host"
    - name: KEYCLOAK_ALWAYS_HTTPS
      value: "true"
    - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
      value: "admin"
    - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
      value: "password"
    - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
      value: "true"

    - name: DB_VENDOR
      value: postgres
    - name: DB_ADDR
      value: <host>
    - name: DB_DATABASE
      value: keycloak
    - name: DB_USER
      value: keycloak
    - name: DB_PASSWORD
      value: keycloak
```

Comment: Thanks @Nataraj. Your response helps this issue https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-13925

Comment: You're welcome. I surprised that you have to put two contractionary terms: switch keycloak to http mode and put KEYCLOAK_ALWAYS_HTTPS to "true". Then it starts working