# Keycloak on kubernetes: ingress HTTPS required error

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-ingress

I have a Kubernetes cluster where I deployed the following deployment and service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
    name: keycloak
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
  selector:
    app: keycloak
    name: keycloak
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    name: keycloak
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      name: keycloak
      labels:
        app: keycloak
        name: keycloak
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
      - name: keycloak
        image: jboss/keycloak
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
            protocol: TCP
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 200m
            memory: 256Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 400m
            memory: 512Mi
        env:
          - name: KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL
            value: "DEBUG"
          - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
            value: "true"
          - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
            value: "admin"
          - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
            value: "password"
          - name: DB_USER
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: postgres-secret
                key: username
          - name: DB_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: postgres-secret
                key: password
          - name: DB_ADDR
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: postgres-configmap
                key: HOST
          - name: DB_PORT
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: postgres-configmap
                key: PORT
          - name: DB_DATABASE
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: postgres-configmap
                key: DATABASE
          - name: DB_VENDOR
            value: "postgres"
```

The logs in my pod where keycloak is running are confirming that my keycloak is running and using the Postgres database that is provided. I try to add the following ingress rules:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: auth.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: keycloak
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /auth
        backend:
          serviceName: keycloak
          servicePort: 8080
```

and I am able to get to the Keycloak home page, but once I click on administration console I keep getting the error: `We're sorry .... HTTPS required`. Setting the PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING variable to "true", did not help to get it right. I don't just want to run keycloak on port 8443, so I am really looking for another solution than that.

Comment: so you want to run Keycloak under HTTPS or plain HTTP? If you want to disable HTTPS then take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337895/globally-disable-https-keycloak

Comment: @VasilyAngapov keycloak has to run under http, since I have a reverse proxy who is redirecting to my ingress controller, Where I have multiple ingress rules, so no need to run it under HTTPS internally. I will check the psql query, but I prefer to not do that. In my other setup where I use my own proxy to redirect to the nodeport of the keycloak service, I am not having this issue. So I hope to just fix this by changing ingress

Comment: if you have external proxy which only uses HTTP then there is no way how you can enable HTTPS for keycloak. You can use only HTTP.

Comment: @VasilyAngapov sorry, my explanation is a little bit confusing. my proxy is using HTTPS. And when I go to `https://auth.mydomain.com` I see the keycloak page. just clicking on admin console, gives me the error

Comment: when you see the error the address in the browser address panel is HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: @VasilyAngapov HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup [TLS termination](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/tls-termination/) within your ingress

```
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - auth.mydomain.com
      secretName: tls-secret
```

With created secret, which contains certificate for `auth.mydomain.com`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: tls-secret
  namespace: default
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data:
  tls.crt:LS0S[...]0tLhsrQo=
  tls.key:LS0t[...]LS1CRUdJ=
```

This will let your ingress controller to terminate traffic using provided TLS cert, and forward un-encrypted HTTP traffic to your `keycloak` service.

Comment: Hi, I'm not a big fan of sharing my crt and key in my ingress rules, after all we already have a SSL-termination proxy who is taking care of that, so it's not necessary to do that twice

Comment: Apparently, you didn't disable SSL  for your master realm. Just run this query with psql client  `update REALM set ssl_required = 'NONE' where id = 'master';`

Comment: This might indeed be a solution, but how should I solve this when I'm running keycloak on k8s without postgres? I deployed keycloak again in standalone mode without using an external database (just for test purposes) and I have the same issue. Is there a way to change things in keycloak or give the right annotations in the ingress rule?

Comment: @SebastienPattyn Even though, you are not using any external databases, Keycloak comes with its own embedded Java-based relational database called H2.  So you can ssh to keycloack and use native sql clinet to run a query i.e.  - java -cp <PATH TO H2>.jar org.h2.tools.Shell -url "jdbc:h2:file:<your DB>" -user <USER> -password <PASSWORD> -sql "update REALM set ssl_required='NONE' where id = 'master'"

Comment: Even after nginx ingress tls termination, I see in my case readiness probe failing