# Keycloak 21.1 behind nginx reverse proxy https redirect

Tags: docker, nginx, keycloak

I'm trying to understand how to stop keycloak to use https. I don't care about security issues since it's just for learning purposes.

I've this `Docker configuration`

```
keycloak:
image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.1
container_name: keycloak
restart: always
environment:
  KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/keycloak
  KC_DB_USERNAME: postgres
  KC_DB_PASSWORD: foo
  KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH: /auth/
  KC_PROXY: "passthrough"
  KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: "false"
  KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: "false"
  KC_HOSTNAME: "myurl.onion:4672/auth"
  KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: "admin"
  KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: "bar"
entrypoint: ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start-dev", "--db=postgres"]
ports:
  - 8080:8080
volumes:
  - /config/keycloak/themes/:/opt/keycloak/themes/
  - /config/keycloak/deployments:/opt/keycloak/providers
depends_on:
  - postgres
networks:
  - nt_int
```

I use nginx to proxy the requests:

```
    listen 4672 default_server;
    listen [::]:4672 default_server;

    root /site;

    server_name _;
    server_tokens off;

    location /auth/ {
            proxy_pass                           http://keycloak:8080/auth/;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header   Host              $host:$server_port;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    }
```

I can reach the main page of keycloak perfectly, but when I click to login to the master realm it says

`Mixed Content: The page at 'http://myurl.onion:4672/auth/admin/master/console/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure frame 'http://myurl.onion:4672/auth/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/3p-cookies/step1.html'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

I've tried to change `KC_PROXY` to `edge` but it didn't solve anything.

I've also tried manually [disabling SSL on the realm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64716153/9890873) but nothing.

Setting `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING` to `true` also didn't solve anything.

I've also tried to use the version `17.0.1` but same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `KC_HOSTNAME_URL` instead of `KC_HOSTNAME` because it includes the scheme and your Keycloak instance "thinks" it is exposed without HTTPS (you are using a reverse proxy for that). Example:

```
keycloak:
image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.1
container_name: keycloak
restart: always
environment:
  KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/keycloak
  KC_DB_USERNAME: postgres
  KC_DB_PASSWORD: foo
  KC_HOSTNAME_URL: "https://myurl.onion:4672/auth"
  KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: "admin"
  KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: "bar"
entrypoint: ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start-dev", "--db=postgres"]
ports:
  - 8080:8080
volumes:
  - /config/keycloak/themes/:/opt/keycloak/themes/
  - /config/keycloak/deployments:/opt/keycloak/providers
depends_on:
  - postgres
networks:
  - nt_int
```

Not sure about `KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN_URL` but if it does not work with that config, try to add this variable also.

*Note: if `start-dev` is used (https://www.keycloak.org/server/configuration) then HTTP is served and "Strict hostname resolution is disabled" by default, so no need to set `KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT`.*

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. IIRC I tried to use `KC_HOSTNAME_URL` without any success. I solved it using another nginx server on another port on the base path `/`.