# Mixed Content the error Mixed Content: The page at {https://frontend_page} was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure frame {http:keycloak}

Tags: reactjs, http, https, frontend, keycloak

I have transferred the frontend using React to a domain with SSL and I want to use Keycloak on HTTP.

Both before when they were on localhost it was okay, now I face an error of mixed content, I tried everything but does not work, now keycloak and frontend have different domains, and they run on different protocols.

Frontend(HTTPs), Keycloak (HTTP). I am using on frontend:
keycloak-js": "^21.0.1

Keycloak version is the latest version pulled from the docker image from jboss/keycloak.

Full error:

```
Mixed Content the error Mixed Content: The page at {https://frontend_page} was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure frame {http:keycloak/auth/realms/master/protcol/openid-connect/3p-cookies/step1.html} This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Also when I run the container, with these env variables:

```
PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
KC_PROXY=passthrough
KEYCLOAK_PROXY=true
```

This is the NGINX config:

```
server {
    if ($host = {Frontend_domain}) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://IP;
            proxy_set_header    Host               $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For    
            $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        }

        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name {Frontend_domain};
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Comment: You can try the answer I add there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78061220/7529228

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would need to configure [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) to be served over HTTPS. If Keycloak is running in a Docker container and you are unable to configure SSL directly, you can use a reverse proxy like NGINX to serve Keycloak over HTTPS.

Obtain an SSL certificate for your Keycloak domain. You can use [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) (Let's Encrypt) or any other certificate authority. Then configure NGINX to reverse proxy to Keycloak over HTTPS:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name keycloak_domain;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/keycloak_domain/fullchain.pem; # Path to your SSL certificate
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/keycloak_domain/privkey.pem; # Path to your SSL private key

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://keycloak_internal:8080; # Keycloak internal URL and port
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    }
}
```

And restart NGINX to apply changes (`sudo systemctl restart nginx`).

Make sure that Keycloak is aware it is being served over a proxy:

- **`PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING`**: Set to `true` to enable Keycloak to build correct URLs in a proxy environment.
- **KC_PROXY**: Depending on your Keycloak version, make sure this is correctly configured to `edge` if you are serving it through an SSL-terminated proxy.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72317811/6309), for Keycloak versions 18.x and later, the use of web-context for setting a custom base URL is deprecated. You now have the `--http-relative-path` argument (or `KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH` environment variable in Docker) for specifying the path relative to the root (`/`).

So you should add (for recent version of Keycloak) to your `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
environment:
  - KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH=/keycloak
```

Or add to your `docker run` command `-e KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH=/keycloak`

That would make sure Keycloak generates URLs (for redirects, service calls, etc.) that correctly reflect the proxy path, helping in the resolution of path-related issues when accessed through a reverse proxy setup.

Finally, update the Keycloak initialization in your frontend code to point to the HTTPS URL of Keycloak.
If you serve Keycloak and your frontend from different domains, make sure [CORS settings](https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/react-cors-guide-what-it-is-and-how-to-enable-it/) are correctly configured in Keycloak to allow requests from your frontend domain.

---

As a workaround, [Magus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1489237/magus) proposes in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77948431/mixed-content-the-error-mixed-content-the-page-at-https-frontend-page-was-l/77967946#comment137507081_77967946)

You can include a meta tag in the `<head>` section of your HTML documents. That tag instructs the browser to treat all of the page's insecure URL requests (http) as if they were secure (https) requests. Here is how you might add it to your HTML:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

Or, in addition to the meta tag, you can configure your server to send the `Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests` header. That approach makes sure all requests, not just those initiated from HTML documents, are upgraded to HTTPS.

It is not a substitute for properly configuring Keycloak to use HTTPS: relying on the browser to upgrade requests can introduce variability in behavior across different clients, and does not address the underlying security concern of transmitting authentication tokens over an insecure channel.

Comment: I am using Keycloak version:  16.1.1.

I put keycloak on HTTPS in a domain, and it works and in the env I have added the new domain:

REACT_APP_KEYCLOAK_URL="https://domain/auth"

And where I open the page it still gives me the error: 

Mixed Content the error Mixed Content: The page at {https://frontend_page} was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure frame {http:keycloak}

Even though in env i put the HTTPs version.

Why is that so, I have port forwarding to the new URL and also put on the new domain to the frontend but still points to the one with HTTP.

Comment: @n9p4 Maybe a cache issue? Or a missing `npm run build`? Anything in the logs? In the realm settings (from the Keycloak admin console)?

Comment: keycloak is aware of its own config and it knows it was setup without https so the js sdk points to the http endpoint, this is a browser only error and you can get around it by using a meta tag https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests